# Baby Rudin Theorem 7.33

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

This is Baby Rudin Theorem 7.33:

[image: Baby Rudin Theorem 7.33]

As far as I understand in both of those cases: $f=\lambda g$ and $f=u+iv$, $u(x)>0$.

I don't understand why $u(x)>0$.

Comment: Note that $f\left(x\right)=\lambda g\left(x\right)>0$ at the chosen point $x$ and if you write $f=u+iv$, then you will have $u\left(x\right)>0$, $v\left(x\right)=0$.

Comment: @Eric So, it means that $\lambda g(x)$ is a real number?

Comment: Yap! Since $\lambda g\left(x\right)>0$, it must be real.